# How to bind object's subproperties with paper-input in Polymer

Tags: javascript, data-binding, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have an object property (`newcontact`) and function (`saveContact`) in one of my Polymer components:

```
properties: {
  newcontact: {
    type: Object
  }
},
saveContact: function() {
  console.log(this.newcontact); // Getting undefined
},
```

I want to add subproperties to `newcontact` via `<paper-input>` data bindings, as seen in the following code:

```
<label class="form-control-label">Name</label>
<paper-input type="text" name="name" is="iron-input" value="{{newcontact.name}}"></paper-input>

<label>Email</label>
<paper-input type="text" name="email" is="iron-input" value="{{newcontact.email}}"></paper-input>          

<label>Phone</label>
<paper-input type="text" name="phone" is="iron-input" value="{{newcontact.phone}}"></paper-input>           
<paper-input hidden is="iron-input" value="{{newcontact.id}}"></paper-input>
<input type="button" value="Save" on-click="saveContact" class="btn btn-primary">
```

But `saveContact()` always logs `undefined` for `this.newcontact`. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting properties of your `newcontact` object with the input fields. However, that object has never been initialised. You can do that in your `properties` definition by giving it a value.

```
properties:{
    newcontact:{
        type: Object,
        value: function() {
            return {};
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: Thanks, it was due to initialization!!